# Any easier way to do $\int^\infty_0 e^{-(x^2+\frac{\alpha^2}{x^2})\beta^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\beta}e^{-2\alpha\beta^2}$

Tags: calculus

I have a textbook proof which i am finding complex - $\int^\infty_0 e^{-(x^2+\frac{\alpha^2}{x^2})\beta^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\beta}e^{-2\alpha\beta^2}$

Any simpler way to do this?

Comment: What is the proof given by your textbook?

Comment: It is not possible for us to know whether our method is 'simpler' if you don't provide the *'textbook proof'*.

Comment: integrated with repect to \alpha. Understood the proof but it was messy. I was thinking of other way. Any way to use double integrals. Stuck up in that.